# How to correctly validate using an onsubmit statement in an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate an HTML form with some javascript code I've written, but when I create the form with this tag

```
    <form name="inputForm" action="http://postcatcher.in/catchers/51eefe8cd1c7b60200000530" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

the form submits without fail despite violating a condition detailed in the validateForm() function I have written.  I have quadruple checked the function and I'm almost positive that nothing is wrong there.  Am I using some sort of syntax incorrectly here or is my problem elsewhere?

EDIT: Here is the validateForm() function in a nutshell

```
function validateForm() {
if(document.inputForm.Title===null || document.inputForm.Title==="") {
    alert("Title required");
    document.inputForm.Title.focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

EDIT 2: The problem was unrelated to the code posted, I had forgotten to set an id for one of the fields in the form.

Comment: Please submit the validateForm() code as well. Then we can see what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: it should be title not Title.

Comment: @GauravSharma that's the name I gave it, with a capital T.

Answer (score 1):

I use the same logic to prevent double clicks with javascript. Make sure that your function ValidateForm returns false if the form is not valid.

My Example:

```
function FirstSubmitOnly() 
    {
        if (haveSubmitted)
             return false;

        haveSubmitted = true;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It returns false. The function I've written has similar structure to yours but with more conditions.

Comment: My form is: <form id="Form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return FirstSubmitOnly();">  And works ok. When you open the page do you get any javascript error?

Comment: No javascript errors.  The form is created without fail when it should be failing

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `value` attribute from the object.

```
document.inputForm.Title.value
```

So your js should be like

```
function validateForm() {
if(document.inputForm.Title.value===null || document.inputForm.Title.value==="") {
    alert("Title required");
    document.inputForm.Title.focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

Moreover, `document.inputForm.Title.value` will never be `null`. So in if condition,

```
if(document.inputForm.Title.value==="")
```

will also work

Answer (score -3):

You should not add events (onsubmit) to html element, instead use event-handlers :) My native JS is not that well in this area, I use jQuery allot:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(event){
    if( validateForm() !== true ){ event.preventDefault(); } 
});
```

that would be something allong the lines of this:

```
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit=function(){ 
    return validateForm()}; 
}
```

Are you sure your function return true/false? Because your inline code returns the returnvalue of the function, are you sure there is any?

Comment: Instead of silently downvoting, I'd like an explanation. Inline eventhandling is a no-no, I gave an example of how to do it in jQuery, took the time to find how to do it natively and asked to verify wether his function has a returnvalue.